# Who introduced the concept of topological mixing?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ho.history-overview, ergodic-theory, mixing

I am writing an introduction and I want to know who introduced the concept of topological mixing?

Comment: The definition is due to Adler, Konheim and McAndrew from 1965. You can find this and more on wikipedia. Their work was motivated by Rohlin's 1959 paper which contains the definition for metric spaces (V. A. Rohlin, Entropy of metric automorphism, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR124(1959), 980-983.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Topological mixing is called "permanent regional transitivity" (and demonstrated) by Gustav Hedlund in his 1939 [article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183501760) on the dynamics of the geodesic flow in constant negative curvature (third page). I think this is the first occurrence of the concept.